# How do I make a <span> element a regular tab stop within a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I made a form control which uses  as its container (see the Yes/No toggler below)

[image: toggle example]

Here's the code for that:

```
<span class="toggle">
    <i>Yes</i>
    <i>No</i>
    <input type="hidden" name="toggle-value" value="0">
</span>
```

My CSS isn't relevant to the question, but it's included for comprehension of my control:

```
.toggle { width:auto; height: 20px; display: inline-block; position: relative;  cursor: pointer; vertical-align: middle; padding: 0; margin-right: 27px; color: white !important;}
.toggle i { display: block; padding: 0 12px; width: 100%; height: 100%; -webkit-border-radius: 12px; -moz-border-radius: 12px; border-radius: 12px; text-align: center; font: 11px/20px Arial !important; text-transform: uppercase; }
.toggle i:first-child { -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset; box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset; background-color: #73B9FF; }
.toggle i:last-child { -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset; box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset; background-color: #cc0000; position: relative; top: -20px; z-index: -1; }
.toggle.on i:first-child { z-index: 1; } /* they overlap but on click they switch who gets to be on top. */
.toggle.on i:last-child { z-index: -1; }  
.toggle.off i:first-child { z-index: -1; }
.toggle.off i:last-child { z-index: 1; }
.toggle.off i:last-child:before { content: " "; display:block; position:absolute; left:1px; top:1px; text-indent: -9999px; width: 18px; height: 18px; -webkit-border-radius: 11px; -moz-border-radius: 11px; border-radius: 11px; z-index: 1;  background-color: #fff; } /* circle */
.toggle.on i:first-child:after { content: " "; display:block; position:absolute; right:-23px; top:1px; text-indent: -9999px; width: 18px; height: 18px; -webkit-border-radius: 11px; -moz-border-radius: 11px; border-radius: 11px; z-index: 1;  background-color: #fff; } /* circle */
```

and the JS that makes it all work:

```
.on('click', '.toggle', function(){
    var input = $(this).next('input');
        if(input.val() == 1) {
            $(this).removeClass('on').addClass('off');
            input.val(0).change();
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('off').addClass('on');
            input.val(1).change();
        }
}
```

***The problem is*** that I'm using this all over my application for data-entry. Have you ever wanted to NOT use the mouse when you're entering a lot of data? Yeah, me too. So you hit TAB and a toggle like this should respond to the spacebar. But instead, since it's just a  element, it is skipped altogether.

I'm hoping someone can help me solve the question of "*how the heck do I make this a tab stop AND be in the correct order*"?

**==============
EDIT: HERE IS MY UPDATED JQUERY CODE CONTAINING THE SOLUTION:**

```
$('.toggle').click(function(){
    var input = $(this).next('input');
        if(input.val() == 1) {
            $(this).removeClass('on').addClass('off');
            input.val(0).change();
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('off').addClass('on');
            input.val(1).change();
        }
}).focus(function() {
    $(this).bind('keydown', 'space', function(e){
        $(this).trigger('click')
        e.preventDefault();
    });

}).blur(function() {
    $(this).unbind('keydown');

}).attr('tabIndex', 0);
```

Comment: Look into the html attribute [`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-tabindex)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try setting your tabindex to 0, on the non-anchor elements you would like to make "tabbable". For example `tabindex="0"`. This way, you won't mess with the tabbing order, or have to throw tabindexs all over the place.

Comment: just as another little note on this, because the control is using SPACE, I needed to prevent the browser from scrolling down, so I added the preventDefault() function to it.

Comment: Note that you need to catch the key event (spacebar) on the `span` element to make it react as you want.

Answer (score 2):

Look into the html attribute [`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-tabindex). Basically you should be able to set `tabindex` on each input you want to focusable via the tab key. Start the first one a `1` and just count upwards for each input. If you also want to take an input out of focusing via the tab key set the `tabindex` to `-1`.

Comment: This is the only way I know so far, but the problem I am running into is that none of the other form controls have tabindex set explicitly, so when I set my <span tabindex="n"> it's all out of order. Plus, I'm trying to do this in the toggle object itself so that it need not rely on manually setting tabindex on every other form control- this is a BIG database site and that would be a nightmare

Comment: @mydoglixu Correct, my suggest is to set *all* of the input's `tabindex`s.

Comment: I edited my comment above to address that- it has to be set somehow by the toggle control only, it's not possible to go back and set all of the inputs like that

Comment: @mydoglixu in that case, I would recommend instead of using a span + a hidden input field, use a radio button styled. This way it will only tab over 1 of them per name. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tocghw8h/)